# Call function as a route-handler?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a REST-api and have rendering function that looks like this:

```
render = (req, res) => {
    var output = {},
        async = [],
        detailed;

    if(req.user){
        detailed = req.user.obj.detailed();
        async.push(detailed);
    }
    if(Object.keys(req.query).length){
        output.params = req.query;
    }
    if(req.validationErrors().length > 0 ){
        output.errors = req.validationErrors();
    }
    sequelize.Promise.all(async).then((response) => {
        if(response.length > 0){
            output.user = response[0];
        }
        res.json(output);
    });
};
```

It grabs stuff and ouputs it like a JSON. It's usually run as the last function in any request:

```
app.all('/user/me', auth, render);
```

In the app I also validate input data at different stages. If the input fails, I want to go straight to the rendering. In order to avoid passing around req/res all over the place, I would like to somehow go to that routing, rather than calling the function, like I am now, is that possible? I can't use next, because sometimes there are more than one function left.

```
    validate = (tests) =>{
        req.assert(tests);
        //Go to render if validation fails.

        //req,res
        if (req.validationErrors().length) {
            return render(req, res);
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook up some [Error-handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling) that runs your standard render method. Then your route validations would need to generate an error.